Can't build a flet application
When running the command
flet build apk --include-packages flet_audio 

in the terminal, the following error occurs:
Running package command
Creating asset directory: C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_build_wAsXq4KTiM\app
Copying Python app from C:GMusic to C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_temp3d0525fd
Configured mobile platform with sitecustomize.py at
C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_sitecustomize9bff01a6\sitecustomize.py
Installing dependencies with pip command to
C:\Users/bahti/AppData/Local\Temp\serious_python_temp3d0525fd\__pypackages__.
Extracting Python distributive from
C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-shared-install_only.tar.gz to
C:\Users/bahti/AppData/Local/Temp/hostpython3.11.8efa2473.
Compiling Python sources at C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_temp3d0525fd

Error building Flet app - see the log of failed command above.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Help please
Most likely the matter is in the requirements.txt file which contains: requests, asyncio, yt_dlp.
Without it, the application can be easily build
This is what I got with the command flet build apk --include-packages flet_audio -vv:
Flutter executable: C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.BAT
Dart executable: C:\src\flutter\bin\dart.BAT
Flutter bootstrap directory: C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_WJNQbHGjmq
Additional Flutter dependencies:
{'flet_audio': 'any'}
Creating Flutter bootstrap project from gh:flet-dev/flet-build-template with ref 0.22.1...OK
Customizing app icons and splash images...OK
Generating app icons...
Run subprocess: ['C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\dart.BAT', 'run', 'flutter_launcher_icons']
Resolving dependencies in `C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_WJNQbHGjmq`... (3.5s)
Downloading packages...
Got dependencies in `C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_WJNQbHGjmq`.
Building package executable... (2.0s)
Built flutter_launcher_icons:flutter_launcher_icons.
  ════════════════════════════════════════════
     FLUTTER LAUNCHER ICONS (v0.13.1)
  ════════════════════════════════════════════

• Creating default icons Android
• Overwriting the default Android launcher icon with a new icon
• Overwriting default iOS launcher icon with new icon
Creating Icons for Web...
Creating Icons for Windows...
Creating Icons for MacOS...

✓ Successfully generated launcher icons
OK
Generating splash screens...
Run subprocess: ['C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\dart.BAT', 'run', 'flutter_native_splash:create']
Building package executable... (2.2s)
Built flutter_native_splash:create.
[Android] Creating default splash images
[Android] Creating dark mode splash images
[Android] Creating default android12splash images
[Android] Creating dark mode android12splash images
[Android] Updating launch background(s) with splash image path...
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-night/launch_background.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-night-v21/launch_background.xml
[Android] Updating styles...
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-v31/styles.xml
[Android] No android/app/src/main/res/values-v31/styles.xml found in your Android project
[Android] Creating android/app/src/main/res/values-v31/styles.xml and adding it to your Android project
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-night-v31/styles.xml
[Android] No android/app/src/main/res/values-night-v31/styles.xml found in your Android project
[Android] Creating android/app/src/main/res/values-night-v31/styles.xml and adding it to your Android project
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml
[iOS] Creating  images
[iOS] Creating dark mode  images
[iOS] Updating ios/Runner/Info.plist for status bar hidden/visible
[Web] Creating images
[Web] Creating images
[Web] Creating background images
[Web] Creating CSS
[Web] Updating index.html
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                       NEED A GREAT FLUTTER DEVELOPER?                      ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║                                                                            ║
║   I am available!  Find me at https://www.linkedin.com/in/hansonjon/       ║
║                                                                            ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

✅ Native splash complete.
Now go finish building something awesome!  You rock! 
Like the package? Please give it a  here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

OK
Packaging Python app...
Run subprocess: ['C:\\src\\flutter\\bin\\dart.BAT', 'run', 'serious_python:main', 'package', 'C:\\GMusic', '--mobile',
'--platform', 'mobile', '--dep-mappings', 'flet=flet-embed', '--req-deps', 'flet-embed', '--exclude', 'build',
'--verbose']
Building package executable...
Built serious_python:main.
Running package command
Creating asset directory: C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\flet_flutter_build_WJNQbHGjmq\app
Copying Python app from C:\GMusic to C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd0b5409e
Configured mobile platform with sitecustomize.py at C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_sitecustomizeaec2f58c\sitecustomize.py
Installing dependencies [requests, asyncio, yt-dlp, flet-embed] with pip command to C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd0b5409e\__pypackages__
Extracting Python distributive from C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\cpython-3.11.6+20231002-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc-shared-install_only.tar.gz to C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\hostpython3.11_c5c2ad96
VERBOSE: C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\hostpython3.11_c5c2ad96\python\python.exe -m pip install --isolated --upgrade --target C:\Users\bahti\AppData\Local\Temp\serious_python_tempd0b5409e\__pypackages__ requests asyncio yt-dlp flet-embed
VERBOSE: Collecting requests
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for requests from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c3/20/748e38b466e0819491f0ce6e90ebe4184966ee304fe483e2c414b0f4ef07/requests-2.32.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached requests-2.32.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.6 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting asyncio
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for asyncio from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/22/74/07679c5b9f98a7cb0fc147b1ef1cc1853bc07a4eb9cb5731e24732c5f773/asyncio-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached asyncio-3.4.3-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting yt-dlp
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for yt-dlp from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/94/dc1cbc7f47bb61fdb33ca440e03140b677e81a3b91bac6bede8c0d46ab9f/yt_dlp-2024.5.27-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Downloading yt_dlp-2024.5.27-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (167 kB)
VERBOSE: ------------------------------------- 167.7/167.7 kB 402.8 kB/s eta 0:00:00
VERBOSE:
VERBOSE: Collecting flet-embed
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for flet-embed from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/48/ac/87ab4306db144af3a76405176f3ad05e09ede01e20ff938c68df09c0fbea/flet_embed-0.22.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached flet_embed-0.22.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.0 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting charset-normalizer<4,>=2 (from requests)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for charset-normalizer<4,>=2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/76/e6222113b83e3622caa4bb41032d0b1bf785250607392e1b778aca0b8a7d/charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached charset_normalizer-3.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (33 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting idna<4,>=2.5 (from requests)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for idna<4,>=2.5 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e5/3e/741d8c82801c347547f8a2a06aa57dbb1992be9e948df2ea0eda2c8b79e8/idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached idna-3.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 (from requests)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for urllib3<3,>=1.21.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/73/a68704750a7679d0b6d3ad7aa8d4da8e14e151ae82e6fee774e6e0d05ec8/urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached urllib3-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.4 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for certifi>=2017.4.17 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ba/06/a07f096c664aeb9f01624f858c3add0a4e913d6c96257acb4fce61e7de14/certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached certifi-2024.2.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting brotli (from yt-dlp)
VERBOSE: Using cached Brotli-1.1.0.tar.gz (7.4 MB)
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: started
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: started
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Installing backend dependencies: started
VERBOSE: Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
VERBOSE: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Collecting mutagen (from yt-dlp)
VERBOSE: Obtaining dependency information for mutagen from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/7a/620f945b96be1f6ee357d211d5bf74ab1b7fe72a9f1525aafbfe3aee6875/mutagen-1.47.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
VERBOSE: Using cached mutagen-1.47.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
VERBOSE: Collecting pycryptodomex (from yt-dlp)
VERBOSE: Using cached pycryptodomex-3.20.0.tar.gz (4.8 MB)
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: started
VERBOSE: Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: started
VERBOSE: Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'.```


error doesn't show any details which could explain problem. Maybe run with option --verbose (or -v) and maybe it will show more details. With -vv it should show even more details

I used -vv, you can see in my question what it gave

error shows problem with requirements which can suggest problem with file requirements.txt. You could search problem also in flet issues: for example flet build apk fails · Issue #2821 · flet-dev/flet

the application could not build due to asyncio and yt-dlp, I removed asyncio and replaced yt-dlp with pytube and everything worked for me
